# Synthesis verilog with Yosys

Tags: vhdl, yosys

I want to synthesis a vhdl design for ASIC standard cell libraries to find the circuits area requirement.
How can i do it for for Virtual Silicon (VST) standard cell library UMCL18G212T3 or UMC L180 0.18µm using Yosys?
Does Yosys support vhdl code or do i need to write it in verilog?

Comment: [VHDL Frontend Efforts](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/wiki/VHDL-frontend-efforts). GHDL-synth: [https://github.com/tgingold/ghdlsynth-beta](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdlsynth-beta) Requires a minor patch to the yosys Makefile. Most of the heavy lifting is actually done in [https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/tree/master/src/synth](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/tree/master/src/synth).

Comment: how to map it to a virtual silicon library?

Comment: Do you have the VHDL source?

Comment: Real silicon libraries are expensive. Fork out a $100.000 and get the library from the vendor.

Comment: actually i dont need to fabricate an IC. Yes i have the implementation, i need to map it to any free standard cell library to see area requirements. does not matter which library. its just an acadamic exercise

Comment: VHDL - no, forget about it. Use Verilog, just like the rest of the industry does. As for the rest, see http://opencircuitdesign.com/qflow/

Comment: @SK-logic what about the standard cell libraries, are there free open source standard cell libraries?

Comment: Yes, OSU cell libraries are open source and come with QFlow. I guess they should be sufficient for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Via the Yosys [webpage](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/about.html). It looks like only Verilog.

> About
>
> Yosys is a framework for Verilog RTL synthesis. It currently has
>   extensive Verilog-2005 support and provides a basic set of synthesis
>   algorithms for various application domains. Selected features and
>   typical applications:

Also from the same page...

> Example Usage
>
> Yosys is controlled using synthesis scripts. For example, the
>   following Yosys synthesis script reads a design (with the top module
>   mytop) from the verilog file mydesign.v, synthesizes it to a
>   gate-level netlist using the cell library in the Liberty file
>   mycells.lib and writes the synthesized results as Verilog netlist to
>   synth.v:

```
> # read design  read_verilog mydesign.v
> 
> # elaborate design hierarchy hierarchy -check -top mytop
> 
> # the high-level stuff proc; opt; fsm; opt; memory; opt
> 
> # mapping to internal cell library techmap; opt
> 
> # mapping flip-flops to mycells.lib dfflibmap -liberty mycells.lib
> 
> # mapping logic to mycells.lib abc -liberty mycells.lib
> 
> # cleanup clean
> 
> # write synthesized design write_verilog synth.v
```